# LinkedIn API Ruby/OAuth2 integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm trying to write an integration with the LinkedIn API for my Rails app using `OAuth2` but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make authenticated API calls. I can't seem to find any resources on the topic that don't rely on the linkedin gem. I already have that gem installed in my app, but need to make some API calls that are not possible using that gem.

What I want to do is set up a controller with some endpoints that my Angular client can ping. When the client pings the controller, it should in turn ping the LinkedIn API. Once it gets a response it will perform some operations to store the information in the database and then pass it along to the Angular client.

I found a single [code sample](https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/code-samples#toggleview:id=ruby) in Ruby from LinkedIn, which I'm attempting to modify into a controller for my app. Here is my controller:

```
class Employers::LinkedinApiController < ApplicationController
    require 'net/http'
    layout 'employers/layouts/application'
    before_action :authorize_viewer
    skip_after_filter :intercom_rails_auto_include

    REDIRECT_URI = 'http://app.mysite.local:3000/linkedin/callback'
    STATE = SecureRandom.hex(15)
    CLIENT = parameterize(client.auth_code.get_token(STATE, redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI))

    def get_update(update_key=nil)
        company = current_employer.company
        update_key = company.social_media_posts.where("linkedin IS true AND linkedin_id IS NOT NULL").last.linkedin_id
        page_id = company.linkedin.page_id
        end_point = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/#{page_id}/updates/key=#{update_key}?format=json"

        access_token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client, CLIENT['token'], {
            :mode => :header,
            :header_format => 'Bearer %s'
        })

        response = access_token.get(end_point)

        # Do something with the response to save it to the database

        # Pass response on to Angular client
        respond_to do
            format.json { render json: response }
        end
    end

    private

    #Instantiate your OAuth2 client object
    def client
        OAuth2::Client.new(
            ENV['LINKEDIN_APP_ID'], 
            ENV['LINKEDIN_APP_SECRET'], 
            authorize_url: "/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code",
            token_url: "/uas/oauth2/accessToken",
            site: "https://www.linkedin.com"
        )
    end

    def parameterize(string)
        parameters = {}
        string.split('?')[-1].split('&').each do |param|
            parameters[param.split('=')[0]] = param.split('=')[-1]
        end
        parameters
    end

    def authorize_viewer
        if !employer_signed_in?
            redirect_to new_employer_session_path
        end
    end
end
```

In the code sample from LinkedIn, the only way to get data from the `accept` method is to ping the `authorize` method, whose callback points to the `accept` method. What I can't figure out is how I can ping the `get_update` method in my controller and make an authenticated API call, without having to set up an `authorize` method that calls back to `get_update`.

How can I do this?